# Server scripts on kinvey

Tags: kinvey

I have implemented a Login module in Kinvey. I am able to write data in the data store. I want to check if the user logging in is already present in the data base. How can I write a business logic for this? How can I call this code in business logic from the client?

I am doing a simple web login, trying to get a grip on kinvey, I fail to understand the business logic part, before-after-save :( , How do I pass values to my business logic

Comment: Hello,  Just a few questions:  What are you developing the Login module for (iOS, Android, etc.)?  When do you want to check if the user is already present?  Can you give me some details on your use case so I can help provide you the best solution?

Comment: updated post, your help is much needed, I cant figure this out, any example, link will be awesome

Comment: Are you trying to check if the user exists for the purpose of seeing if they are already logged in, or to see if they exist as a user at all?

Comment: exist as a user at all

Answer (score 2):

I am an engineer at Kinvey.  There is a REST endpoint that allows you to check the existence of a username, so there is no need to utilize business logic.  Simply POST to http://baas.kinvey.com/rpc/:appKey/check-username-exists.

For authorization, use your appKey:appSecret.

```
POST /rpc/:appKey/check-username-exists HTTP/1.1
Host: baas.kinvey.com
Authorization: [app credentials]
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "username": "the-username-to-check"
}
```

This will return a response with true or false:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "usernameExists": "false"
}
```